# Phaser - Show graphic objects for 50ms and destroy for each key press when one or more key presses occur simultaneously

Tags: javascript, graphics, settimeout, phaser-framework

I want to show a rectangle for `50ms` when user presses a key. `draw()` function works as expected for single key press. If multiple keys are pressed simultaneously say, two keys at same time then, one of the graphics object doesn't get destroyed.

```
function draw(x, y){
    graphics = game.add.graphics(x, y);
    graphics.clear()
    graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x0000FF, 1);
    graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, 0.5);
    graphics.drawRect(0,0,18,18);
    graphics.endFill(0x0000FF, 0.5);
    // destroy the graphics after 50 ms
    setTimeout(function (){graphics.destroy()}, 50);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Your second draw call (done in time less than 50ms) assigns a different object in graphics so when timeout callback from the first draw call is fired it operates on graphics created in the second call.

To avoid it You can: 
1) make a local variable out of graphics (add var/let)
2) use graphics.destroy.bind(graphics) as timeout callback